# Is the following Eigenvalue inequality holds or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can anyone help me with the following problem?
Suppose $u=(u_1,u_2,...u_n)^T$, $e=(1,1,...1)^T$, and we have $u\geq e$. Now for any symmetric matrix $A\in S^n$ with $diag(A)=0$, can we claim the following
$$
\lambda_{max}(uu^T+A)\geq\lambda_{max}(ee^T+A)?
$$ 
where $\lambda_{max}$ represent the largest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix.

Thanks!

Comment: What meaning of inequality do you intend for $u\geq e$? The obvious is term-by-term, but then I'd have expected notation like $(u)_k>1$.

Comment: That's just meaning that $u_k\geq 1$ for every k from 1 to n @Semiclassical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we cannot.
Consider $$ A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -2 & 2 \\
 -2 & 0 & -2 \\
 2 & -2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and $u=(1,2,1)^T$. Then $\lambda_{\rm max}(uu^T+A)=4$, but $\lambda_{\rm max}(1+A)=(5+\sqrt{17})/2\approx4.6$.

**OLD ANSWER**

I am assuming that the inequality you want to prove is term-by-term also. I do not understand why you cannot simplify the $A$ term on both sides of the inequality.

If ${\rm diag(A)=0}$, ${\rm tr}(A)=0$. Therefore $\sum \lambda=0$, which implies that $\lambda_{\rm max}\ge0$.
If $\lambda_{\rm max}=0$, the inequality is trivial.
If $\lambda_{\rm max}>0$, we can simplify it from the inequality, leaving to prove that $$uu^T\ge ee^T,$$ which is clearly true since for any $u_ku_{k'}\ge 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think there is some problem in your answer. Yes, we do have $tr(A)=0$, but thus we can only claim $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(A)=0$. The reason we can not simplify the A term on both sides is the following. Note that both $uu^T$ and $ee^T$ are matrices in $S^n$, and for two matrices $X$ and $Y$, we can not say that $\lambda_{max}(X+Y)=\lambda_{max}(X)+\lambda_{max}(Y)$. Hence, we also can not say $\lambda_{max}(uu^T+A)=\lambda_{max}(uu^T)+\lambda_{max}(A)$.

Comment: @user150183 I see, so $\lambda_{\rm max}$ is a function. Now I understand.

Comment: Yeah, $\lambda_{max}$ is a function, not a scalar. Really appreciate your attention and patience :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really shows the inequality can fail for some cases.